# Linkage Error while calling a static method from a pointer to instance

Tags: c++

While compiling the code below, VC++ complains about linkage error in the main file for the function `getProfile()`. The function has been declared `static` and defined; but I don't think that's the problem. Have I missed anything? Am I calling a static method in a wrong way?

main.cpp

```
IComponent * componentInterface = init((IKernel *) kernelInterface);
Profile componentProfile = componentInterface->getProfile();
```

IComponent.h

```
class IComponent{
        public:
            static bool startComponent();
            static bool stopComponent();
            static Profile getProfile();
        };
```

EDIT:

```
Error MessageError  1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class Profile __cdecl IComponent::getProfile(void)" (?getProfile@IComponent@@SA?AVProfile@23@XZ)  C:\...\Implementation\main.obj  Moniware
```

Comment: Fatal OP error K2065: missing error message.

Comment: Please show your cpp file as well. How do you implemented getProfile() function.

Comment: The message says it: the function `IComponent::getProfile` has not been defined as you think (merely declared). Can we see the definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static function should be called:

```
 IComponent::getProfile();
```

You don't need object or pointer of `IComponent` to call static function.

But as you mention you are getting linker error, this means you missed the implementation: linker was not able to find implementation.